# Using GPG is there a way to label public keys on my OpenPGP keyring?

Tags: gnupg, pgp, openpgp

I am unable to identify certain public keys on my keyring because the key owner generated their public key using a UID that contained no identifiable information. For instance they're  completely lacking of an identifying email address that many will use as the the key UID when generating their key.

I would like to be able to label each of these keys with a unique name so I know who they belong to. Is there a way to do this with the set-notation or cert-notation options in gpg? Or is there another more elegant solution to this problem where I can add arbitrary strings to specific keys at my discretion so I may better keep track of them?